# Bitnami MEAN stack can't connect to local mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to connect to my local mongodb with my node express app hosted on litghtsail MEAN bitnami.

The connection string im using with mongoosse client look like this: `mongodb://app:sang@127.0.0.1:27017/prisedesang`

Im able to connect whit that user remotely with a SSH tunnel. Im able to connect with that same user localy using mongo cli.

However when I use the app I get  `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I try to connect to the db hosted on the same server... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using MongooseJS? You can connect your application with MongoDB using MongooseJS, an object modeling driver for Node.js. It is already installed in the MEAN stack so you only have to add the following lines to your `app.js` file:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = Mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/DATABASE');
```